# awk + verify field if zero

Tags: bash, awk

To find if field 5 has I use the:

```
   [[ -z ` echo $LINE  | awk '{print $5}' ` ]]
```

my question if there is another elegant way to verify if field 5 is zero?

THX
Yael

Comment: provide example lines

Comment: LINE=123 aaa ddd ggg ttt yyy hhh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `length5=$(echo $LINE | awk '{ print length($5)}')`
the variable `$lenght5` will contain the length of field 5;

Note: in your example line, if ttt were empty, yyy would be field 5, so be careful: you can use

`awk -F' '`

instead of `awk` to make the space the field delimiter, so that 2 spaces = empty field....

Answer (score 0):

This will pass if the 5th field is the string `0` (and won't if it's `00`, `0.0`, or it's absent etc).

```
#!/bin/bash

LINE="123 aaa ddd ggg 0 yyy hhh"

if [[ "0" = `echo ${LINE}  | awk '{print $5}'` ]]
then
   echo "5th field is string '0'"
else
   echo "5th field isn't string '0'"
fi
```

Does that do what you want?

It would be useful if you provided more example input.